# Algebraically closed fields minimal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

**STATEMENT:** This is a portion from Lang's proof of theorem 2.8 in chapter V section 2.

If $E$ is algebraically closed, and $L$ is algebraic over $\sigma k$, then $\sigma E$ is algebraically closed and $L$ is algebraic over $\sigma E$, hence $L=\sigma E$. Where $\sigma: k\rightarrow L$ is an embedding.

**QUESTION:** I wanted to ask if algebraically closed fields are necessarily minimal. That is if $F$ is an algebraically closed fields, does there exists a proper subfield that is also algebraically closed?

Comment: It depends. Given any field $F$ there is always a minimal field extension of $F$ that is algebraically closed, we call it the algebraic closure of $F$ and usually denote it $\bar F$. But nothing prevents us from having a further (necessarily, not algebraic) extension of $\bar F$ that itself is algebraically closed. This larger field, $K$, has $\bar F$ as a subfield. For example, $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, and has *many* algebraically closed subfields. For example, if a field is countable, so is its closure. But $\mathbb C$ is uncountable.

Comment: Then my question is how does Lang conclude that $L=\sigma E$ in the statement above?

Comment: $L$ is algebraic over an algebraically closed field. If you understand what this means, the result is clear. Since you are asking, this probably means that you are unclear on the meaning of some of these terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The algebraic closure of the rationals is [countable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number#Properties), and is contained in $\Bbb C$ (the algebraic closure of the reals), which is uncountable. Any algebraically closed field does contain a minimal algebraically closed subfield: the algebraic closure of its [prime subfield](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSubfield.html).

In response to your second question, note that any *algebraic* extension of an algebraically closed field is trivial (and since $L/\sigma E$ is algebraic, $L = \sigma E$); this is because, given $x \in L$, $x$ is algebraic over $\sigma E$, hence contained in $\sigma E$ by algebraic closure. The example given above of $\Bbb C/\overline{\Bbb Q}$ is not an *algebraic* extension.